# Navigation drawer fragment - TextWatcher crashes

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio, textwatcher

I am trying to add a TextWatcher method to a fragment loaded through the navigation drawer:

```
  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }

    testMethod();
}

public void testMethod() {
    EditText tv_filter = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editText);
    tv_filter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int count, int after) {
        }
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                  int before, int count) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "INPUT TRACKED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

The problem is, whenever i load this fragment, the app crashes with the following logcat message:

```
    08-26 12:00:26.553  12842-12842/fest.test.dk.fest E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: fest.test.dk.fest, PID: 12842
java.lang.NullPointerException
at fest.test.dk.fest.menuFragment.testMethod(menuFragment.java:74)
at fest.test.dk.fest.menuFragment.onCreate(menuFragment.java:66)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1766)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:917)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:740)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1501)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:458)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Usually the logcat will be pretty specefic with the errors, but I am unable to figure out exactly what this error means.

Comment: would adding paranthesis help!!  (EditText) (getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editText)).
ignore if its silly :)

Comment: where id `editText` is declared ?

Answer (score 0):

getActivity() is probably null. Shift the call of testMethod.  Override onAttach in the fragment and call it from there. Read up on the fragment lifecycle again.

Comment: getActivity() is not null, as the toast works fine (if i remove the textwatcher that is)